# jquery selector to get element value when you have nearby element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have below html code snippet. In java script i have html element  with id `<input id = "Test[0]name">`. Now i need to get the value of  next select element whose id is ending with address

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input id="Test[0]name">
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input>
            .......
            <select id="Test[0]address">
            <label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

I tried below

```
$(element).parent().parent().parent().siblings()[2].find("[[id$=address]]")
```

Comment: Is it possible to amend the HTML? This would be much simpler (not to mention more semantic) if you can add a common parent container for both elements.

Comment: have you tried `$('#Test[0]address')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its already there. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IDs are unique, so this should be:

```
$('#Test\\[0\\]address')
```

or instead of `siblings()` you should use `.next()`:

```
$(element).parent().parent().parent().next().find("[id$=address]")
```

---

If you are able to update your markup little bit, i would suggest you to use a class name on this element `$(element).parent().parent().parent()`:

```
<div>
    <div class='holder'>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input id="Test[0]name">
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
    <div class='holder'>
        <div>
            <input>
            .......
            <select id="Test[0]address">
            <label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='holder'></div>
</div>
```

Then you can change to this:

```
$(element).closest('.holder').next().find("[id$=address]");
```

Comment: I'm assuming the OP doesn't know the specific `id` at runtime and is looking to traverse the DOM to find the required element.

Comment: @Jai, you're welcome, but you have (probably accidentally) reverted them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi actually i was writing other possible solution for the issue.

Comment: @Jai, okay, but those two slashes to escape the square brackets in your first code snippet should still be backslashes :)

Comment: ohh! i thought that was overridden, i mean your changes were also included with my updates.

Comment: @Jai its not working.
`$(element).parent().parent().parent().next().find("[id$=[0]address]") ` but its says undefined
but when i do `$(element).parent().parent().parent().next().find("select").val()` it gives me value why its not working with id ending with [0]address].